# How create a field of sequential number with autoincrement() that start from zero in arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I would like to create sequential numbers in a field of a  point shapefile  that start from 0 with an interval of 0.050.
The main code works whenever the start number is not zero.

The original code to put in the codeblock from (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137) looks like this:

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(): 
   global rec 
   pStart = 1 
   pInterval = 1 
   if (rec == 0): 
      rec = pStart 
   else: 
      rec += pInterval 
   return rec
```

How I can make it in arcpy with a “codeblock” and “Expression”?

Comment: just change rec=0 to something like rec=-999, set pStart=0 and pInterval=0.05 and then update 'if (rec == -999):' this should solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function which yields incrementing values:

```
import arcpy
fc = r"Buildings" #Change
seqfield = "SeqField" #Change

def frange(start, end, step):
    tmp = start
    while(tmp < end):
        yield tmp
        tmp += step

seq = frange(0,100000,0.5)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, seqfield) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = next(seq)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]